# Problem setting color in toolbar (android-kotlin)

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

I'm having a problem with my toolbar.

I want the device app and toolbar to be the same color, but don't use findviewbyid. (I'm migrating the entire project just to view binding
)

OK behavior (using findviewbyid).

[image]

NOK behavior (using view binding), is giving a little misalignment of the textView, it seems to receive a margin that was not placed.

[image]

But if I declare different in onWindowsInsetsChanged method or don't use it, I get another problem, the color is not correct.

[image]

Using findviewbyid:

```
 override fun onWindowsInsetsChanged(view: View, insets: WindowInsets, padding: InitialPadding) {
        with(binding) {
            val toolbar  = fragmentEditObjectiveNameRoot.findViewById<View>(R.id.toolbar)
            toolbar.updatePadding(top = topInset)

            editObjectiveNameRoot.updatePadding(
                bottom = insets.systemWindowInsetBottom
            )
        }
    }
```

Using view binding:

```
override fun onWindowsInsetsChanged(view: View, insets: WindowInsets, padding: InitialPadding) {
        with(binding) {
//calling the include toolbar and the root of the toolbar fragment

            toolbar.viewImageToolbar.updatePadding(
                top = topInset
            )

            editObjectiveNameRoot.updatePadding(
                bottom = insets.systemWindowInsetBottom
            )
        }
    }
```

Different declaration in onWindowsInsetsChanged:

```
override fun onWindowsInsetsChanged(view: View, insets: WindowInsets, padding: InitialPadding) {
        with(binding) {
//calling root from fragment and instead of calling the include toolbar and its root

            fragmentEditObjectiveNameRoot.updatePadding(
                top = topInset
            )

            editObjectiveNameRoot.updatePadding(
                bottom = insets.systemWindowInsetBottom
            )
        }
    }
```

I would like to leave the same color behavior when using findviewbyid, but with view binding, but without losing textView alignment.

Here is the xml that receives the toolbar include:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/fragmentEditObjectiveNameRoot"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/editObjectiveNameRoot"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/bgColorFrameLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/color_frame_layout_height"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/toolbar" />

        <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scrollView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/toolbar">

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/screen_margin_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/screen_margin_horizontal"
                android:paddingBottom="16dp">

                <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
                    android:id="@+id/cardView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/bari_white"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/card_corner_radius"
                    app:cardElevation="0dp"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:padding="@dimen/card_padding">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/titleSubAccount"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text="@string/sub_account_control_settings_edit_name"
                            android:textAlignment="center"
                            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                        <br.com.bancobari.core_ui.views.text_input.BariTextInputLayout
                            android:id="@+id/nameInputLayout"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
                            app:helperIconEnabled="true"
                            app:helperStart_enabled="true"
                            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/titleSubAccount">

                            <br.com.bancobari.core_ui.views.text_input.BariTextInputEditText
                                android:id="@+id/nameEditText"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:inputType="textPersonName|textCapWords"
                                android:maxLength="16"
                                android:textAlignment="center"
                                android:textSize="16sp" />

                        </br.com.bancobari.core_ui.views.text_input.BariTextInputLayout>

                    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

                </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>

                <br.com.bancobari.core_ui.views.SubmitButton
                    android:id="@+id/saveButton"
                    style="@style/DefaultButton.Icon.Arrow"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
                    android:text="@string/objective_settings_save"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/cardView"
                    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

        <include
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            layout="@layout/view_image_toolbar" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Here the toolbar xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/viewImageToolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:minHeight="@dimen/custom_toolbar_height"
        app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
        app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
        app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/custom_toolbar_height" />

    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/iconEmojiView"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:textSize="22.5sp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/toolbarTitleTextView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/toolbarTitleTextView"
        tools:visibility="visible" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/toolbarTitleTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:fontFamily="@font/nunito_bold"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:lines="1"
        android:textColor="@color/text_neutral_gray_800"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/viewImageToolbar"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:text="Teste" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/toolbarRightIconImageView"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_settings"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/toolbarTitleTextView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/toolbarTitleTextView" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: In your `findViewById`, you're searching for the view with ID `toolbar`, but with your view binding reference, you are using the view with ID `viewImageToolbar`, so not the same layout element.

Comment: @Tenfour04 yes, in the first case using `findViewById` I access the `include toolbar` ID and I can access the `updatePadding` method, in the second case if I use the `view binding` to access the `include toolbar` ID, I cannot use the `updatePadding` method that I just used what I did, calling `toolbar.viewImageToolbar` to be able to use the `updatePadding` method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first block of code with `findViewById`, this

```
val toolbar = fragmentEditObjectiveNameRoot.findViewById<View>(R.id.toolbar)
```

returns the ConstraintLayout at the root of your included layout with the ID toolbar.

The property `toolbar` in your binding is another binding for the included layout rather than the root view of that layout. The `root` property of that included binding in this case is the same ConstraintLayout from above, so you should use instead:

```
toolbar.root.updatePadding(
    top = topInset
)
```

What you were doing was changing the padding of an inner view of your complete Toolbar layout, the `viewImageToolbar` element.

Comment: oh jesus, i didn't think about using the root this form, thanks man, you save my day.